# Android MediaRecorder recorded MPEG4 AAC audio files header incomplete

Tags: android, media, mp4, aac, recorder

I've got this android app (compileSdkVersion 23, minSdkVersion 16, targetSdkVersion 23) that records audio files using Android MediaRecorder.

This is the way I start recording

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(2);
mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(mMaxRecordLength);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
mMediaRecorder.start();
```

and the way I stop recording

```
mMediaRecorder.stop();
mMediaRecorder.reset();
mMediaRecorder.release();
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

when the recorded audio is longer than 1 minute and 50 seconds the header of the file seems to miss some information about the file content; I need these files to be played on a player that checks the informations inside the files (not only the file name extension) and, in this way, it's not able to recognize my recorded files when the duration is greater than 1:50 minutes.

I recorded many files of many lenghts to understand what was going on, at the end I opened the files with a Hex Editor and this is what I found:

- FILE LENGHT 1:50 MINUTES OR LESS [**GOOD FILE**]:

  ```
  ....ftypmp42....isommp42..T.moov...lm

  vhd..................................

  ..................................@..

  ................................ymeta

  ...!hdlr........mdta................+

  keys............mdtacom.android.versi

  on...%ilst............data........6.0

  .1..S.trak...\tkhd...................

  .....................................

  ................@.............Scmdia.

  .. mdhd...............D.Jk........,hd

  lr........soun............SoundHandle

  ...S.minf....smhd...........$dinf....

  dref............url ......R.stbl...[s

  tsd...........Kmp4a..................

  .......D.....'esds...........@......w

  ...w............stts.................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................



          [CUT of so many dots and not much more]


  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  ......V...#........stsc..............

  ..........stco..........T....'free...

  ..............................A.mdat.
  @"....------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  ---------------.....6.tfZ...........(

  .Q*k...P..@.........?.H.....H\a...H=.

  .?.H.R..4a...7.....cTB~O.._e.......

  ......Z!.=s462.e.]."b...|a..[...uK...

  ...g.. .q.W,..6[...KO.R.j.5@W....B9dj

  1B....UK,.K3[-.=..;3...x.3.;r.u....|

  .)......."..e.YA.r..Y@.f..y...<.R.).,

  .:.....<..)..UT..X5.Q)..UTb2...5.....

  ...C.b=.7.O....yk.M...gH.=.`z.0..X..4

  S....j.G.\....|...DI.d....QE...6*....

  T....TD....Q*...|..~..z.........:.W.v

  ...w..m.9n......Yw..(PRRWm..Z.*..&.f.

  .....\;[.c]YY#[53AC9.=..R.j...)5.....

  ...:.....R.A'&jYR...SEb....Ef..f.cEy.

  v.J3.d...P../2.....-.d..MR.;4jb..)EbA

  r.......Q%5.......2.A..,!.EEe?.tO... 

  ..e......C.$......N.Q..QB..I1i%...3T.

  ...C..d"Q.*2..<........S.4...{H...]..

  ....!4.N...Mr... ..ze"..%=..~....r`F;

  ....2.......M.....6)..4...a .*.\.....

  .P.JE].EM.....}X.My~..z..k.;^_.......
  N...._...=..:..pd5.._H..... L.?...nk.

  W.n1.Ct^....m...?WnR..........`F{.~.Y

  2..V....`\.GCL......)1..<..4...l))...

  8%..0J....g..V....9.;..H'.%4...!.E%.P

  .W ....x...8...........BL.Y..1.A.eL.

  ...Xf.&...'w....c...nY.<7 .z.........

  .)....a..!.7O.........O...X....8...6

  )......A1./-.fq.Wc-WWK..J.r.:.G.|_6..

  _.<....T-...A.y...........hw..m..F.

  .F.........n....L..D...m.e..n..S)....

  ...ia...@....F..............v...I....

  .s;bb&...J.&.!w.)..@.M.Z[*.:e=.....(.

  .1.1I.&...........r.f...xR..!....H...

  [Y.......A}..#..`*..+.....S.A...C...

  TYtI;.y2.w....u.P./.J.3..."....[2V..K

  ...C...6*....B..#u....u..%".T.R.D.}.'

  .nZ..\.`.............o.........3..md

  ...A.!J.$....sF.S-...........=/]Mg...

  ...]].......zm.....DE.d.e=.T...B.....

  ...[..s>.+:0......O...:..A8..S....8..

  6W)....Ue..s.....`eC......,'\LzMa...

  ...w........_.+I.q.u-g...X.o(.....w..

  .,.)..>t..rH8E......I...H.C.i.S.-..8.

  p..6*.....Vn....X.*A..........$..@..q

  \..|.Cl..2..B.........zi.p.q.3....)..

  -..m%..B.].pm..f...~a)x...R.E;.c.....

  ..=P......l|.........:.+Mj...}.b6.N..

  W.......kY..,v6`....EH_p...d..X..w.p.


          [and so on]
  ```

---

- FILE LENGHT 1:51 MINUTES OR MORE [**BAD FILE**]:

  ```
  ....ftypmp42....isommp42..T.free.....

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................

  .....................................



          [CUT of so many dots and nothing else]



  .....................................

  .....................................

  ..............................kumdat.
  @"....------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  -------------------------------------

  ---------------.....6-......"0P&&D...

  Q*.t(J..d.....5x...Y.}m..'...Z`....~.

  ..w...d.J.N....y./.\..|U:>....Ol.}[(.

  ..Qe.v.\...gq..7..N..5..K.Au>......>3

  .cr.I.....a....=Y..A..9As........U.[.

  ..RK..15#[g... .....@.....F"....@8...

  >Fb.~<.nY...n#..S..#...W0....|..0...S

  ...Q]$t..J..$_PN.._y..I...}.=..t....

  VfP..|?p?]N...6-t8M...P...\.."!.*....

  ........U2.>7......s...~n...[..%....)

  ..o..W...V.+.-.r*....E....C&.z..l.}..

  Qzr.G...|.D.....^.u.6^5q..`....J..8..

  ._.....kIV?%.T.......&......Bg$.(.N.O

  .N. d,E).2..d...E/.-.!..d.....H.`*,..

  ..vr....-0...@^....dUME!.l....K..m...

  ...T.......

  A.....Y..\..Os-#X..j^.....R|n.......

  ^...9..._U..D.s.

  .e.F^.,....8..6)V(."..aA.p.(..9.....L

  .Q..w.t.R.....EK%8w...1{...Uyo.....PN

  .p..........w..~.V.1...y.#.i...).....
  .6.@..(9n..&u%.o..q..<.Z7.......&Q.B.

  M....<..A...nM..b8...E .=..C..;\...$ 

  .....lD..`0...H..z....A.e........C..c

  ..zv...d...1.Qy..p.(L.3"A.g../.....7.

  .......3.j+_%b.G......QX'....'..,.3.j

  .T.........SZ^.tIe..X...Z/......Z..2.

  S.8..6).....Ac.."..sZ....uQ...b.[.:^.

  .6G+..}....n7.|F..T9._.2"N.g....*....

  ."R..iZ....9.Z..B.s$...<.N.:...L...

  ......9w.x...Dt..3,Iy........85....(.

  .'..9..F*.w..p..&#....P...)...&....H.

  p.....KL.

  .@.....z...-.:[...A5.9@....kb...T.ke.

  a_~.4.#P.Or..$.I...9..8...Q[A.Xu+..f.

  .&9...6.4.<...A.. ..72.}9.r.TT...P...

  ,n.+....N........Mx.~z..s}.7..nw.,..

  .Q.v...z_x........+q.{.~M._....DL...

  i.9y..Y6v(..3h.....5.t..d.c....7..*(

  pt..3T..=1(."...,.Y..1c....5.....I6..

  V.J....-..$4Z.o.E3..1....w,.(..K&...|

  ..0s.....w.T~...f......y.Tq.$.r5{....

  .FB...,......./...Ig-5%..B`$.Y.oF...

  ..6*.x....a8.,b....2Ew......"RT..M.V.

  .Z..N...}...F._......3....2<...r..SI"

  ..`.......s[.$.T...Q.h$b{.k-x..]..+..

  .YA.)p. $&..Du.....wWZ....B_$o...a:..

  j2.._.;2n.&p....qy~.wQ,.E..ag9..7}.

  .....5.P.kC..yzx^...9.<.z...D]TS..4Z.


          [and so on]
  ```

As you can see in the BAD FILE, after the first line there is a bunch of dots where in the GOOD FILE there are informations.

Can you explain me what's going on and what could I do to fix my problem?

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem was?

Comment: no, unfortunately the problem is still there; my need was and is to play the recorded files on a custom hardware player, at the moment we updated the player.

Comment: OK for me I was using AudioRecord to receive the raw audio and writing to file using MediaMuxer but I was doing it wrong. I was able to fix it.

Comment: I got the same problem when I called `mediarecorder.stop()` right after `mediarecorder.start()` hence mediarecorder failed to write file properly. Interestingly thought it's a [documented behaviour](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#stop())

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov when you say "mediarecorder failed to write file properly" do you mean that the file is somehow invalid or that the file is not present at all? If the file is present are you able to play it on some player (software or hardware) or it is too "corrupted" and is unusable?

Comment: @heartear, it present but misses important header `moov` which contains duration of the video and should be present at the end of a file (in my case)